# I want to make a function that saves data on a text file with a varying title input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
   void function(double a, int b,..., string filename)
ofstream Zone1H;
        Zone1H.open(filename);
        for(int i=0; i<j; i++)
        {
        Zone1H<<ZoneHeliostat[i].r*cos(ZoneHeliostat[i].angle)<<"   " <<ZoneHeliostat[i].r*sin(ZoneHeliostat[i].angle)<<endl;
        }

int main()
{function(a, b,.., filename); getch();}
```

The first question is how do I make this filename as an input. I want the file to be saved as an text file.

Another question is how can I change the file name with for loop.
For example I will iterate this function 10 times

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){funciton(..., filename i)}
```

Basically I want the filename to contain the value i. So that I can know which file is is which.

Comment: It would help if you added the programming language tag instead of rather generic tags.

Comment: Please specify language and a little more context, such sa where the filename retrieved from, whether just saving to directory and example of what you need saved.

Comment: From the syntax I guessed it to be java. But it has a `main()` method without args which makes it c

Answer (score 0):

Either accept the file name as a command line parameter... Or simply use the IO facilities provided by the language? Either way you will have to parse the input and verify its a valid file name for the operating system that the code is running on ... Which is not trivial.

Even if you aren't worried about cross platform compatibility, file IO is typically not something you should be implementing yourself. Find a library which has already done all of the hard stuff for you.

Finally, your last question begs another question. If you want to change the file name in the loop, it's easy enough to do that with a string array. The question is how you are going to accept that as an input. My guess is an input directory with all of the files together, which is again, something you are going to want to use a library for.

Hope this helps.